# Firebase CLI: execute arbitrary Firebase Authentication requests to Firebase Emulator

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cli

Using the Firebase CLI, I'm executing arbitrary JavaScript that's stored in a file. In that script, I'm trying to make calls to `admin.auth().something()`, but it doesn't work against the Firebase Emulator. This is in contrast to making calls to Firestore, which works perfectly fine with the Emulator.

### Firestore (everything works)

##### GCP

This makes calls to Firestore on GCP and it succeeds:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp({ projectId: 'my-project' });
const db = admin.firestore();

(async () => {
  const widget = await db.doc('/widgets/123456789').get();
  console.log(widget.data().name);
})();
```

##### Emulator

This also succeeds:

```
const admin = require('@firebase/testing');
const db = admin
  .initializeAdminApp({ projectId: 'my-project' })
  .firestore();

(async () => {
  const widget = await db.doc('/widgets/123456789').get();
  console.log(widget.data().name);
})();
```

### Firebase Auth (GCP works but Emulator does not)

##### GCP

This makes calls to Firebase Auth on GCP and it succeeds:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp({ projectId: 'my-project' });

(async () => {
  const user = await admin
    .auth()
    .getUser('user123456789');

  console.log(user.email);
})();
```

##### Emulator

This fails:

```
const admin = require('@firebase/testing');
const auth = admin
  .initializeAdminApp({ projectId: 'my-project' })
  .auth();

(async () => {
  const user = await auth.getUser('user123456789');

  console.log(user.email);
})();
```

The error message is:

```
C:\Users\...\node_modules\@firebase\testing\node_modules\@firebase\component\dist\index.cjs.js:134
                throw e;
                ^
[t [Error]: Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.] {
  code: 'auth/invalid-api-key',
  a: null
}
```

I'm not sure what API key they're referring to, as the request is against the Emulator. How can I execute Firebase Auth requests against the Emulator using Firebase CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send requests against Firebase Emulator Auth, set the following environment variables and use the standard Firebase Admin SDK (`firebase-admin`) instead of using `@firebase/testing`:

```
process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST = 'localhost:9099';
process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST = 'localhost:8080';

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp({ projectId: 'emulator projectId' });
```

Now this works:

```
(async () => {
  const user = await auth.getUser('user123456789');

  console.log(user.email);
})();
```